# rewriting a pseudo element horiz. to vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I have code which creates an element at the bottom of a div to act as an 'arrow/pointer' pointing down.

I need it written so that the 'arrow/pointer' points to the left

curent code  -

HTML

```
<div style="background-image:url('...');">
    <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

mask css is in fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hunt0194/gu1sgotd/

I've tried changing 'bottom' values to 'left' values, etc. But can't get it to work

code creates the two black shapes which act as 'masking' out the bottom of the div

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go here [css-triangle-generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) , generate your own triangle css.  It is a lot easier than the code you are currently using.

using

```
border-width: 100px 100px 100px 0;
border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
```

will create the desired triangle effect, you can play around with the page and get it just right

Comment: how can i apply that to my code? i need the 'triangle' to be masked out, not created

Comment: Edited my question with image

Answer (score 0):

Try adding at `.indx-img`

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
```

at `.mask`

```
left: 10%;
```

---

```css
.indx-img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 16% 0;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.mask:before {
  border-left: 0 none;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  left: 0;
}
.mask:after {
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0 none;
  right: 0;
}
.mask:before,
.mask:after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mask {
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="indx-img">
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gu1sgotd/4/

Comment: i think you misread what I am looking for, I need the arrow on the side of the div pointing left. I believe my code adds a bar with an arrow cut out nd placed at the bottom. I need it to be rotated to the side. i don't need a triangle created

Comment: Edited my question with image

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 4px solid #FF0000;
  height:150px;
}
.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right-color: #FF0000;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right-color: #FF0000;
  border-width: 36px;
  margin-top: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
  <div class="arrow_box">

  </div>
</div>
```

Made using [CSS ARROW PLEASE!](http://cssarrowplease.com/)

Comment: I think perhaps I'm asking the question wrong. I do not want to create an arrow/triangle. It needs to be masked out. The arrow is INSIDE the div. My code creates the bars outside the arrow, not the arrow itself. This code creates an arrow and puts it outside the div